# Nginx / php query string

Tags: php, nginx

So i have a url like this to display images on some html this is how it works right now

```
subdomain.example.com/?img=foo.png
```

I was wondering if it was possible to hide the ?img= part of the url so the url would look something like this

```
subdomain.example.com/foo.png
```

And still make the page show the html and css i have in my code

Answer (score 1):

Use rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/(.*) /?img=$1 last;
```

Comment: Thanks @SuddenHead i will try this ;)

Comment: Hey i did that part that you put above that works great but i was wondering if there was a way to have it redirect to the page with the html which has it's own of displaying the image?

Comment: so you have index.html which contains <img src="foo.png"> ?

Comment: I will try this @SuddenHead

Comment: when i add that to my server block and reload nginx and access an image link i get a 500 Internal Server Error do you know what might be causing it?

Comment: I got this error in the error log [error] 12273#0: *4982 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php"

Comment: please have a look